# Angular2 and Typescript do i need to declare models for each api call

Tags: angular, typescript

Coming from Angular 1 background, I used to have all my models declare as POCOs and my web api calls returned the data.

```
 datacontext.query('api/OwnerData/GetOwners').then(function (d) {
            vm.domain = d;
}
```

Now with Angular2 and Typescript, I have two options. Either i can use map and get a JSON object and assign it to a property in the component and then use it on view.

```
this.http.get(`/api/OwnerData/GetOwners`, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
        .map(r => r.json())
        .catch(handleError);
```

Or else, I can use a different mapping function to map it to a strongly typed object. But if I go on this path i will have to define entire domain model in back end in typescript. Plus a suite of methods to map them. I feel this is a too much work and repetitions. On the other hand if I go with the JSON then I will loose the type safety.

What are your thoughts on this. Thanks for your time. (i am using Angular 2.4 and Typescript 2.1.5)

Comment: Make a service to call your API..

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast to interfaces that match JSON exactly. This way you get autocompletion and compilation errors, but you don't need to implement any methods. Interfaces are ignored at runtime. Therefore you don't get any type safety at runtime.

```
interface MyData {
  a:string;
  b:number;
}
```

```
this.http.get(`/api/OwnerData/GetOwners`, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
    .map(r => r.json() as MyData)
    .catch(handleError);
```

Comment: Is '<MyData>r.json()' and 'r.json() as MyData' are same? Is first startement also typecasting json response int some type? I'll appreciate you reply @Gunter

Comment: Yes, both do the same. Not sure what you mean with " Is first startement also typecasting json response int some type?"

Comment: Sorry for typo mistake but I got the answer.

Comment: Just to be sure, this is only for more convenient development (autocompletion, type checking during compilation), **it doesn't have any effect for code execution**. If the received JSON doesn't match the interface, this won't cause an error at runtime.

Comment: So to handle negative scenario(unmatched JSON), how should we achieve this functionality.

Comment: Then it's probably best to just create classes as interfaces with a constructor that parses the JSON and assigns its values to fields.